British children's cartoon about a sailor
I have a TV theme song stuck in my head. Please help me identify the TV show so I can listen to the song.
It was a catchy sea shanty, and I'm pretty sure it was played on a concertina.
Here's what I remember:

I'm pretty sure it was a cartoon.
It was sea based, I think, about a sailor, maybe a pirate.
Pretty sure it was British
I remember from the early to mid 90s.

It's not Spongebob or sailor moon.

Sounds like Captain Pugwash, from the mid '70s.  It is British cartoon series and had the sea-shanty theme tune.  An updated series aired in 1998.
Here is the theme tune on YouTube.

OH YEAAA... do dodo do do dodo do do daa ... THAT'S IT!. I'm cured!

@Coomie - glad to be of service.  As someone from the UK who was the target audience of this show in the mid-70's this was a very easy guess.
